# segmentation fault using protobuf

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have started to learn protobuf, so please go gentle on me.

My protofile:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package apple;

message Message {
    repeated int32 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
    wife mywife = 3;

    enum phonetype
    {
        INVALID = 0;
        MOBILE = 1;
        HOME = 2;
    }
    phonetype type = 4;    
}

message wife
{
    string her_name = 1;
    int32 age = 2;
    enum sex
    {
        INVALID = 0;
        FEMALE =1;
        MALE=2;
    }   
    sex orient = 3;
}
```

My C++ file:

```
using namespace google::protobuf;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    apple::Message msg;
    msg.add_id(77);
    msg.set_name("xyz");
    auto w_msg = make_shared<apple::wife>();
    w_msg->set_her_name("abc");
    w_msg->set_age(88);
    w_msg->set_orient(apple::wife::MALE);
    msg.set_allocated_mywife(w_msg.get());
    cout << w_msg->her_name();
    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles and build fine but when I run it gives me a segmentation fault, running with Valgrind gives me an invalid read error with too much information which I could not understand. I assume I am doing something wrong in `msg.set_allocated_mywife(w_msg.get());` but I don't know exactly what? My purpose is to set Message message from already created wife message.

Comment: Please post the full `valgrind` error as people here will understand it and it will help us debug.

Comment: That's `proto2` not `proto3`, Ken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `set_allocated_X` in protobuf, you **transfer ownership**.

You should not access that type via `w_msg` after you call `set_allocated_wife(...)`.

You should not use a shared pointer for the constructed `wife` object, either, since that assumes that ownership is controlled by the (potentially many) `shared_ptr`s.

Here is some code (based off of yours) that works properly and still lets you modify the `wife`.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    apple::Message msg;
    msg.add_id(77);
    msg.set_name("xyz");
    auto w_msg = make_unqiue<apple::wife>();
    w_msg->set_her_name("abc");
    w_msg->set_age(88);
    w_msg->set_orient(apple::wife::MALE);
    msg.set_allocated_mywife(w_msg.release());
    cout << msg.mywife().her_name() << '\n';
    auto* modifyable_wife = msg.mutable_mywife();
    modifyable_wife->set_her_name("abc");
    cout << msg.mywife().her_name() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A side note: you don't need to create the submessage yourself and transfer ownership later: `mutable_<field>` gives you a pointer, owned by the message, which you can modify. 

You can just do `apple::wife* w_msg = msg.mutable_mywife();` and operate on that.

Comment: Good call -- I made the assumption that the user wanted explicitly to use `set_allocated_X` -- not sure if that's the case.

Answer (score 3):

You gave Gender as `MALE` for `wife`. That's why it gave segmentation fault

Comment: Then what. It won't have any error. You can assign anything to a variable in programming.

Comment: 2 people didn't get the joke, which was so bad that I'm giving it one upvote.